# CSS Toggle Button incorrect logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button that I want to change every time it is clicked. It is working correctly, except for the fact that it doesn't change on the first 2 clicks. What is wrong with my logic?

```javascript
 var soc_selected = new Boolean(false);
    $('#soccer-button').click(function() {
          if (soc_selected == false) {
              $('#soccer-button').css('background', 'url(assets/img/sports/soccer_us.png)');
        soc_selected ^= true;
    }
    else if (soc_selected == true){
        $('#soccer-button').css('background', 'url(assets/img/sports/soccer.png)');
        soc_selected ^= true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest you to create class and use function `$.toggle()`

Comment: Can you provide demo? Its difficult for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to js in general. Let me do that real quick . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need all these strange manipulations with XOR, which actually result in integer, but not a boolean?

You can make it much simpler:

```
var soc_selected = false; // not Boolean(false)
$('#soccer-button').click(function() {
    var bg = soc_selected
        ? 'url(assets/img/sports/soccer_us.png)' 
        : 'url(assets/img/sports/soccer.png)';

    $('#soccer-button').css('background', bg);

    soc_selected = !soc_selected;  
});
```

In my opinion, it looks much more transparent and clear now.

**Another good option** is to define styles in CSS classes and do the following:

```
$("#soccer-button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('us');
});
```

It will also solve the problem with necessity to set the initial background.

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/892fcmqv/1/).

Comment: This worked perfectly! I think it was partly because I had a boolean object.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `soc_selected ^= false;` in your second condition if `soc_selected == true`.

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/thv1dogs/)

Answer (score 1):

You might have some issue with your Boolean logic.

```
var soc_selected = new Boolean(false);
```

This line actually creates a Boolean `object` as oppose to a simple primitive.

So when you do the line comparison here the first time. The `soc_selected` **name** is evaluated and NOT its value so the `if` condition is actually `true == false` in your code.

```
      if (soc_selected == false) {
          $('#soccer-button').css('background', 'url(assets/img/sports/soccer_us.png)');
          soc_selected ^= true;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var soc_selected = new Boolean(false);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#soccer-button').click(function() {
      if (soc_selected == false) {
         $('#soccer-button').css('background', 'yellow');
  soc_selected ^= true;
 }
 else if (soc_selected == true){
   $('#soccer-button').css('background', 'red');
   soc_selected ^= true;
 }
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="soccer-button">click me</button>
```